# Sorting table with rst and python-sphinx in html output

Tags: html, sorting, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'd like to offer my visitors the possibility to sort the cells in the tables in an HTML page generated from RST with python-sphinx. Let's suppose I have a table like this:

```
.. list-table:: A fancy name table
   :header-rows: 1
   
   * - Family name
     - Given name
   * - Smith
     - Samuel
   * - Johnson
     - John
```

This renders well and shows the name in the order of the input. Now I'd like to generate an HTML output and offer the user the possibility to reorder the names into alphabetical order. There are [standalone examples](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp) and libraries to implement this, and I'd like to know which solution has already implemented into Sphinx if any. The best would be to include a minimal extension and modify a property of all the tables (or just the one I'd like to be able to sort) to include this feature.

Could you please advise an extension and best practice how to do it? I'd prefer to make the least possible CSS and JS code/file manipulation myself.

Comment: I don't know of any extensions in https://github.com/sphinx-contrib?q=table&type=&language= That leaves implementing something like https://datatables.net/ by modifying your theme.

Comment: Any luck so far?

Comment: @Felix I didn't try to modify the theme, because I do not want to maintain a whole theme just for this. I think addiing a static file could solve this issue. Someting like [this could be added](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inspired by some answers already provided I created the following solution which uses dataTables. I am using the html theme 'classic' which already includes jquery (I'm not sure about the other templates).

In `conf.py` add additional css and js files:

```
html_static_path = ['_static']

html_css_files = [
    'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css',
]

html_js_files = [
    'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
    'main.js',
]
```

Create the file `_static/main.js` and add the following lines (I've chosen to use a class "datatable" to explicitly enable this feature on a table):

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('table.datatable').DataTable();
} );
```

In your rst document you can now create a fancy table:

```
.. table::
   :class: datatable

   =====  =====  =======
   A      B      A and B
   =====  =====  =======
   False  False  False
   True   False  False
   False  True   False
   True   True   True
   =====  =====  =======
```

The `:class: datatable` adds a class to the table element, consequently the DataTable javascript is applied on this table.

Comment: I was able to make it work, but only with a grid table, and specifying a class as rst-class: 

.. rst-class:: datatable

Another catch is there must be a header row, otherwise dataTables produces an error.

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time. [Example](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/properties.html)

Might not be the best way, but I insert a regular html table under `.. raw::` html and add a link to the JS in my `layout.html` template.  View source to see my html code.

Comment: This is potentially s great answer. Please add the relevant code here!

Comment: The table can be defined in RST syntax (as in the example) and many other ones. Forcing the user to use HTML restricts the possibilities and degrades the flexibility of rst.